# Modern fantasy, werewolf novel, silver teeth

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

I am looking for a modern werewolf story. A man with a troubled home life (I believe he's a psychiatrist) is given a pair of silver wolf teeth in a human 'dentures' set so to speak (it'd fit easy in the mouth) to keep safe. Of course he tries them on. This turns him into a werewolf. At first only at night but gradually he can control it.

While a werewolf he does werewolf things like killing the man his wife is cheating on him with and a bunch of other people too, but eventually 'grows out of it' and only wants to live in peace. Meanwhile he runs into a werewolf lady without knowing she's a wolf too, by accidentally hitting her German shepherd with his car. Dog survives. A werewolf hunter arrives and he flees to the north wilds thinking she's been killed, does some stuff up there, and eventually reunites with her at a cabin. Werewolf hunter shows up with a helicopter. Hunter dies. Other people die. They return to civilization to turn themselves in, everyone thinks they're normal-crazy not actually werewolf crazy and lock them up. They escape and head for freedom by swimming into the sea.

Answer (score 4):

"[Saint Peter's Wolf](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/michael-cadnum/saint-peters-wolf/)" by Michael Cadnum

[image]

> A werewolf novel with teeth, from the author of *Nightlight* and *Sleepwalker* (both 1990). Never has the transformation of man into wolf been portrayed with such psychospiritual intensity as in the narration of Benjamin Byrd, a meek San Francisco psychologist who describes his evolution into a vibrant force of nature. Byrd, an avid "collector," begins his new life when his car clips the dog of the alluring Johanna Fisher. Grateful for his concern, Johanna introduces Byrd to someone who sells him a bizarre set of fangs set in silver. Under their influence, Byrd nightly begins to change at first unwittingly, then consciously into a werewolf, "running in the night." So enamored is he of his new freedom, power, and sensations, and of his infatuation with Johanna soon revealed as a fellow werewolf, also transformed by the fangs that Byrd accepts the accompanying bloodlust, including his killing and eating of two people. However, when his wife leaves him for another man whom he vengefully devours, Byrd tastes remorse which, along with police pursuit of the "Night Beast" terrorizing the city, forces him and Johanna to flee to the Canadian wilderness. There, in a hard but exhilarating plunge into raw nature, Byrd lopes with wolves, fights a wildcat, and eludes hunters; at the same time, he finds himself growing in compassion for all living things, even for the renegade FBI agent who tracks him down and whom he kills. This compassion compels him to return to S.F. to confess his crimes and to destroy the fangs; but, as Johanna warns, "Our lives are rich with surprise" including a cathartic bloodbath and a final dash for freedom. Overlong, overcomplicated, and shamelessly melodramatic, with cliffhanging chapters and much emoting; but Cadnum's swollen style and poetic prose well suit his hero's Byronic status, helping to make this the most romantic and thoughtful of werewolf novels.

Comment: Hi Ken! Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you explain why you believe this is the correct answer?